# Geometric series for values between 0 and 1

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

I am given that geometric series is defined as the following $1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4$ for values in range $0<x<1$.

I am also told expected value can be calculated by using the following equation: $1/1+x..$

Then i am told i can keep calculating the series until  i am in the error range of the expected value.

Error = |currentSumofGeoSeries+expectedValue|

```
Given x = 0.5 and error tolerance =  0.001

Term 1 1 0.333333
Term 2 0.5 0.166667
Term 3 0.75 0.0833333
Term 4 0.625 0.0416667
Term 5 0.6875 0.0208333
Term 6 0.65625 0.0104167
Term 7 0.671875 0.00520833
Term 8 0.664063 0.00260417
Term 9 0.667969 0.00130208
Term 10 0.666016 0.000651042
```

I am just confused as to how term 1 ...term 2 are calculated. how did they get 1 and 0.333 for term 1? please advice

Comment: The series is given by
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-x)^k \to \frac1{1+x} \text{ iff } |x| < 1$$
Your problem is that the last value of the output is the error of the limit $\frac1{1+\frac12} = \frac23$ compared to the truncated sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series is given by
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-x)^k \to \frac1{1+x} \text{ iff } |x| < 1$$
Your problem is that the last value of the output is the error of the limit $\frac1{1+\frac12} = \frac23$ compared to the truncated sum.

The output is formatted like this:

$$\text{Term } k \qquad \sum_{j=0}^k (-\frac12)^j \qquad \Bigg| \sum_{j=0}^k (-\frac12)^j - \underbrace{\sum_{j=0}^\infty (-\frac12)^j}_{= \frac23} \Bigg|$$

---

As per request: calculation of Terms $1$ and $2$:
I denote
$$S_n := \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-\frac12)^k$$
The output of your program then gives $S_n$ and $\epsilon_n := |S_n - \frac23|$.
$$S_1 = \sum_{k=0}^{1-1} (-\frac12)^k = (-\frac12)^0 = 1$$
so
$$\epsilon_1 = |1-\frac23| = \frac13$$
. Now for term $2$:
$$S_2 = \sum_{k=0}^{2-1} (-\frac12)^k = (-\frac12)^0 + (-\frac12)^1 = 1 - \frac12 = \frac12$$
so that
$$\epsilon_2 = |\frac12- \frac23| = |-\frac16| = \frac16$$

Comment: i understand how the last term is but can u show perhaps a run through of how first two terms are calculated?

Comment: @user2733436 I have now done that. Is it clear how to proceed?

Comment: what is Sn and En ?

Comment: @user2733436 I have defined $S_n$ to be the truncated sum (called _partial sum_) and $\epsilon_n$ to be the error $|S_n - \frac23|$.

Comment: also can u quickly tell when do u stop calculating ?

Comment: @user2733436 The condition is that $\epsilon_N < 0.001$ (the error is smaller than the tolerance) This happens first for $N=10$